# Find the taylor series by $f$ at $x=a$

Tags: calculus

I don't know how to expand taylor series, I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right direction, I've tried a few pages on the internet, but still cannot understand how to expand.

The example I've been given is;

Find the Taylor series generated by $f=\frac{2}{x^2}$ at $x=a$ where $a=1$

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Michael, the notation $f^n(a)$ means the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f$ evaluated at $a$. A typical place to start is to list some derivatives of $f$ and evaluate them at $x=a$. For example, $f^0(a)$, the "zeroth" derivative, is just the function $f$, $f^1(a)$ is the first derivative of $f$, and so forth:

\begin{align*}
f^0(a)&=\frac{2}{a^2} \\
f^1(a)&=-\frac{4}{a^3} \\
f^2(a)&=\frac{12}{a^4} \\
f^3(a)&=-\frac{48}{a^5} \\
f^4(a)&=\frac{240}{a^6} \\
\ldots &= \ldots
\end{align*}

We need enough of these to spot a pattern. We assemble this all together by the formula with the sum index starting at $n=0$:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n (a)}{n!} (x-a)^n \\=& \frac{\frac{2}{a^2}}{0!}(x-a)^0+\frac{-\frac{4}{a^3}}{1!}(x-a)^1+\frac{\frac{12}{a^4}}{2!}(x-a)^2 +\frac{-\frac{48}{a^5}}{3!}(x-a)^3+\frac{\frac{240}{a^6}}{4!}(x-a)^4 +\ldots \\
=&\frac{2}{a^2}-\frac{4(x-a)}{a^3}+\frac{12(x-a)^2}{2a^4}-\frac{48(x-a)^3}{6a^5}+\frac{240(x-a)^4}{24a^6}-\ldots \\
=&\frac{2}{a^2}-\frac{4(x-a)}{a^3}+\frac{6(x-a)^2}{a^4}-\frac{8(x-a)^3}{a^5}+\frac{10(x-a)^4}{a^6} -\ldots+\ldots.
\end{align*}

The pattern should now be clear to where most people could write the next term after visual inspection of the prior terms. The first 5 terms were more than sufficient to see it.

You can then substitute $1$ for $a$, or any other nonzero number $a$ you wish to get the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) representation at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Find a general form for $f^n (a)$, where $f^n (x)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$. Then just plug it into the formula for the Taylor series:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n (a)}{n!} (x-a)^n$$

Here's the pattern: First we start with $f(x) = 2x^{-2}$. Then $f'(x) = -4x^{-3}$, $f''(x) = 12x^{-4}$, and so we see from our continued application of the power rule we find the pattern of the derivatives to be $f^n (x) = (-1)^n(2)((n+1)!) x^{-2 - n}$, so when $x = a = 1$ this is $f^n (a) = (-1)^n(2)((n+1)!)$. Thus we have

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n 2(n+1) (x-1)^n$$

(You could combine the $-1$ and $x-1$ to make $(1-x)^n$ if you prefer)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand? How do I find the 'general form'? I'm not taking degree level maths, so I'm struggling quite a lot with jargon etc.

Comment: 'General form' here refers to the idea of taking enough derivatives that you can find a pattern for $f^{(n)}(a)$, which is what you then put into that formula.  Alternatively, do you know how to find the Taylor series for $g(x) = \frac{2}{x}$ about $a = 1$?  If so, you could then take that series and plug in $x^2$, since $f(x) = g(x^2)$.